# Conditional/optional fields in struct type

Tags: go, struct

I have a `Node` struct type like this:

```golang
package tree

// Enum for node category
type Level int32
const (
    Leaf Level = iota + 1
    Branch
    Root
)

type Node struct {
    Children []*Node
    Parent   *Node
    X        float32
    Y        float32
    Z        float32
    Dim      float32
    Category Level
    LeafPenetration float32 // Needed only if category is "Leaf"
    RootPadDim float32      // Needed only if category is "Root"
}
```

I have two fields of `Node` which are optional and only needed depending upon `category` field:

```golang
    leafPenetration float32 // Needed only if category is "Leaf"
    rootPadDim float32      // Needed only if category is "Root"
```

Is the current `Node` implementation fine? What is the best practice for such optional/conditional fields inside struct types?

Comment: Common practice would be to just have the fields be part of the struct. If no node ever can be a "Leaf" and a "Root" at the same time you can spare one field and have a single `additionalData float32 // leafPenetration for Leafs and padDim for Root nodes`. Providing accessor methods with proper names and which check Category might be a good idea. Note that you gain nothing by using pointers to indicate "absence" of these fields.

Comment: "Optional" in what way? In what situation are the fields "required"?

Comment: @Adrian The options are *not* required, since we have defaults for them. But in the case of `Root` node some options might be set, and in the case of `Leaf` node, some other options might be set.

Comment: All fields have defaults no matter what; fields that aren't set get their zero value. I guess my question is, what is the problem if you just ignore the fields you don't need when you don't need them?

Comment: @Adrian Right, actually that's an approach I could take. It would make the code simpler. I just wanted to make sure I would follow the best practice in such situations. My intention was to make sure I'm not missing anything =)

Comment: @Volker Thanks! I'm implementing your suggestion of accessor methods which check `Category`. Just one question, I don't understand this sentence: `Note that you gain nothing by using pointers to indicate "absence" of these fields.`. Does it mean I should *not* use @GrigoriyMikhalkin suggestion of using `*float32`?

Comment: This depends. If you want to indicate „absence“ you can use pointers or NaNs, if the default is 0 there is no need to signal absence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a very simplified approach:

```golang
package tree

// Enum for node category
type Level int32
const (
    Leaf Level = iota + 1
    Branch
    Root
)

type Node struct {
    Category Level
    Parent   *Node
    X        float32
    Y        float32
    Z        float32
    Dim      float32

    RootT  float32 // Root thickness
    RootD  float32 // Root diameter
    RootBR float32 // Root bezel ratio of top-bottom, i.e. top D is larger by this much
    LeafP  float32 // Leaf penetration
}

func NewNode(cat Level, parent *Node, x, y, z, dim float32) *Node {
    n := &Node{
        Category: cat,
        Parent:   parent,
        X:        x,
        Y:        y,
        Z:        z,
        Dim:      dim,
    }
    switch n.Category {
    case Leaf:
        n.LeafP = float32(0.3)
    case Root:
        n.RootT = float32(2)
        n.RootD = float32(30)
        n.RootBR = float32(1.08)
    }
    return n
}
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, fields initialize to type's zero value -- in case of `float32` it's `0`. To avoid that, it's common to use pointers, for fields that are optional, like:

```
type Node struct {
    Children []*Node
    Parent   *Node
    X        float32
    Y        float32
    Z        float32
    Dim      float32
    Category Level

    // Optional fields
    LeafPenetration *float32  // Needed only if category is "Leaf"
    RootPadDim      *float32  // Needed only if category is "Root"
}
```

Pointer fields will be defaulted to `nil`.

Answer (score -2):

Is it a good idea to follow [this guideline](https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#functional-options)?

For example having this `Node` type:

```golang
package tree

// Enum for node category
type Level int32
const (
    Leaf Level = iota + 1
    Branch
    Root
)

type Node struct {
    Children []*Node
    Parent   *Node
    X        float32
    Y        float32
    Z        float32
    Dim      float32
    Category Level
    // https://github.com/uber-go/guide/blob/master/style.md#functional-options
    Opts []Option
}
```

Implementing options like this:

```golang
type options struct {
    penetration float32 // Needed only if category is "Leaf"
    base        float32 // Needed only if category is "Root"
}

type Option interface {
    apply(*options)
}

// penetration option
type penetrationOption float32

func (p penetrationOption) apply(opts *options) {
    opts.penetration = float32(p)
}

func WithPenetrationOption(p float32) Option {
    return penetrationOption(p)
}

// base option
type baseOption float32

func (b baseOption) apply(opts *options) {
    opts.base = float32(b)
}

func WithBaseOption(b float32) Option {
    return baseOption(b)
}
```

With the above approach, the implementation gets too complicated. However it can be expanded further in future. Not sure about its worthy-ness though.

Comment: "Is it a good idea to follow this guideline?" No. This are not configuration options.

Comment: @Volker Well, maybe =) But I think those are configuration options for `Node`. Not sure!